Company offering its employers to other companies for fee
What do you call a company that "rents" its developers to other companies for a fee, it's its main source of revenue?
In Russian, we would call it "аутстаффинговая компания", but it doesn't seem "outstaffing company" is commonly used in English

Outsourcing agency?

@MichaelHarvey doesn't "outsourcing" imply providing services (e.g. software development and maintenance) rather than providing people who deliver those services on the customers' premises? I referred to the latter

It's so confusing. Completely different terms are suggested

If I run a company that hires out developers for other companies to use, I am providing outsourcing services (people as well as processing), either off-site or on-site.

This is a relatively new (last 20 years or so) phenomenon,at least on the international scale, where companies "offshore" the work and it is done remotely, and the terminology has changed over that time.  I don't think any of the names I've seen have gained much traction.  In the US, for many, "outsourcing" has negative connotations, so companies tend to avoid referring to themselves  in that way.  Such companies used to be called "head shops" here in the US, a somewhat pejorative term.

@TimR what term do such companies use to refer to themselves?

"staffing services" is commonly used in the US to refer to tne nature of the business of companies that provide "warm bodies" who will work on site at the customer's location. The company that provides people will use the phrase themselves and so will the customers.

Thank you. So such company is called staffing services company, isn't it?

"XYZ Inc. is a staffing services company". or "XYZ Inc. is a staffing agency." or "XYZ Inc. is a staffing company."   The word "staffing" is consistent but it could be agency or company or provider or possibly something else.

For professional workers, (developers, marketing people, product designers, management consultants), such a firm can be called a consultancy.
The term can be used for companies whose employees work on their own site, or at the client's site.
Here is an example.

We can call them manpower outsourcing services companies:

Manpower Outsourcing Services means supply of skilled and unskilled manpower for carrying out various jobs

lawinsider
